# Problem with setting background image using JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jlabel

I trying to make mini game and this game have option to choose map. Diffrent chooice, choose diffrent map. Every choice have own map ( background image ). For background image I useing JLabel and method: setIcon(). 
My problem is that when I set image, all my components get hide. This is picuture: http://prntscr.com/qi5m8a ( You can see that only image can be seen ).
For map choose I use this structure, here is picture: http://prntscr.com/qi5n4c   There is Play button with event like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if(mapOneRadioButton.isSelected())
    {


        this.dispose();
        GameWindow game = new GameWindow();

        game.setVisible(true);
        game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        backgroundLabelGameWin.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/main/earthProject.gif")));

    }else if(mapTwoRadioButton.isSelected())
    {

    }else if(mapTreeRadioButton.isSelected())
    {

    }else if(mapFourRadioButton.isSelected())
    {

    }else if(mapFiveRadioButton.isSelected())
    {

    } 
}
```

I useing JPanel where I add JLabel for background image and I useing JLayeredPanel for rest of components.

My problem/question is, How can I change/set image without breaking order in my frame ?? I mean, I want to change/set image in background so all my components can be seen. 
Please help me, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: A decent [mre] code post would help you get a decent answer quickly

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sir, What did I miss ? I write down everything that make problem. Enlighten me please, what did I miss ?

Comment: _What did I miss ?_ please use the link provided and ask if something is not clear.  Hint: You're asking us to volunteer to solve your problem, 
 and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Comment: You're getting correct  answers but they are very broad and not specific to your actual code. If they solve the problem, then great, but if not read the [mre] link as it will explain what I requested.

Comment: @c0der Well, I asking you to teach me something new today. This is diffrent way looking at stuff. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For background image I useing JLabel and method: setIcon(). My problem is that when I set image, all my components get hide.

Two options:

1. add the components to the JLabel. Then the components will paint on top of the image. The restriction of this approach is that the components must fit inside the image, since the image is always painted at its actual size.
2. do custom painting of the image on a JPanel by overring the `paintComponent(...)` method of the panel and then invoke the `Grapics.drawImage(...)` method. Then add your components to the panel. See [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a class that provides this support. This provides more flexibility as you can scale the image to fill the panel.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you change the background of the JPanel instead of using a JLabel for image. You can't directly change the background of a JPanel. But you can refer following link to do it
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm

Comment: For some reason it didnt work for me, prbly my bad. Thank you for your time.